# In MongoDB, when deleting a dataset how do I also remove the associated "child" datasets?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Example: If I delete a user, I want to also remove all of that users associated comments.

```
const UserSchema = new Schema(
    {
      username: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
    },
      email: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
    },
      comments: [
      { 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: "Comment" 
      }
    ],
);
```

Right now I am removing a user with the .findOneAndDelete method.

Comment: Figured it out with the $in operator!!